# Hex value in C string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I need to prepare constant array of ANSI C strings that contains bytes from range of `0x01` to `0x1a`. I made custom codepage, so those values represents different characters (i.e. `0x09` represents Š). I'd like to initialise the array in that way:

```
static const char* brands[] =  {
"Škoda",
  //etc...
};
```

How can I put `0x09` instead of `Š` in `"Škoda"`?

Comment: But be aware this is the actual code for `\t`, so you cannot use `\t` anymore because that will also insert an `Š`. Which reminds me: I guess you don't "need" `\n` and/or `\r` either?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recommend not using `"\x09koda"`, use octal or spaced strings.

The problem is that hexadecimal escape sequences are not limited in their length.  So if the next `char` is a hexadecimal character, problems occur.  Use octal, which is limited to 3.  Or use separated strings.  The compiler will concatenate then, but the escape sequence will not accidentally run too far.

```
// problematic
"\x09Czech"
 ^^^^^--- The escape sequence is \x09C, but \0x09 was hoped for

// recommend octal
"\0111234"
 ^^^^--- The escape sequence is \011

// recommend spaced strings
"\x09" "Czech"
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple

```
"Škoda" -> "\x09koda"
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I put 0x09 instead of Š in "Škoda"?

```
"\x09koda"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [escape squences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) - i.e `\x09`

For hex escape you want to use the `\Xnnn`, for octal just `\nnn` and for unicode `\Unnnn`